# Prove or disprove that there exists a family of entire functions F that is not normal in any neighborhood of any z∈C.

Tags: complex-analysis

A family of holomorphic function is normal if and only if it is uniformly bounded on any compact subset of any region.Typically being locally bounded is equivalent to being normal.

Comment: How about the family of constant functions?

Answer (score 0):

Take the family of entire functions $F$ that are not normal in any neighbourhood of any $z \in \Bbb C$. That is the family required.